# why log4j is having a problem parsing url even I have fixed the directory name to English which was Korean

Tags: spring, log4j

while I'm doing my spring project, I got this error message

```
**log4j:ERROR Could not parse url [file:/Users/gim/내폴더/Workspaces/Workspace_final/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/fogams/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml].**
```

so I immediately changed the directory which was named to Korean.
(and it made me to lose all the Workspace that I was working on..so foolish.
but I've re-built it through gitHub)

and now my Workspace directory is

```
/Users/gim/myfolder/Workspaces/Workspace_final/
```

but I still get the same exact error.
so I've tried cleaning server, updating maven project...and never worked.

please help me to find the problem.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wich IDE are you using?! For intellij, you'll need to download sources and reload your project

Answer (score 0):

It was kind of mac system error. when I searched,
people said I need to switch the system country, and then
switch it back to my country.
so I did that and re-opened the Eclipse and it worked!